# How to get NsKeyValueObservationinfo in swift?

Tags: swift

I want to get `observationInfo` message, but I just get address when printing `observationInfo` as per following code:

```
        let info = self.apple.observationInfo

    print("\(info)") //0x0000000100605e50
    debugPrint("\(info.memory)")//"()"
    print("\(info.memory)") //()
```

How to get the whole message of `observationInfo` ?

Answer (score 1):

`observationInfo` has refers to `NSManagedObject` and has been deprecated for a while (since iOS 7.1).

Note that in Swift, we observe values like this:

```
var accountBalance: Int {
   didSet {
       alertAccountHolder()
   }
}
```